# What topics do I need to cover for maths on Deep learning (see screenshot attached)

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

I was recommended to read the book on Deep Learning, however it has some mathematical terms/language in it which I don't quite understand yet.

Can you please tell me which topics I need to cover first to understand the maths (see screenshot attached).

[image]

Also do you have any boioks which you would recommend on the above for maths ?

thanks,

Comment: Your book recommendation request is explicitly off-topic for this site, so you should delete that. I don't know about the rest of your question, since it is about mathematics and education but also relates to deep learning.

Comment: The book "Linear Models in Matrix Form: A Hands-on Approach for the Behavioral Sciences" by J. Brown looks promising. It seems to cover the needed material but in a way which is more focused on statistics and accessible for non-mathematicians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the math topics in that page.

1. **Functions**, as in the first complete line. In the USA that is usually introduced in high school Algebra 2, developed further in Precalculus and Calculus, and expanded more in university Abstract Algebra. You probably don't need that last to understand this book.
2. **Summation**, as in equation 6.1. This is sometimes covered in the sequences and series chapter in Algebra 2 and is also covered in Calculus.
3. **Linear Algebra**, including linear functions, affine functions, and matrices. This is the bulk of that page. That is covered in Finite Mathematics, Discrete Mathematics, and in (of course) Linear Algebra.
4. **Linear Regression**. This is often taught as part of Statistics.